# Laravel polymorphic nested relations showing unexplainable behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-5

I am using polymorphic relations to handle reporting of both recipes and comments. I have no problem getting the polymorphable object included in my queries, but the problem comes when I wish to also include the owner (user) of said polymorphic object.

At first I attempted the following:

**Attempt 1.** Controller Function:

```
public function getReports() {
    return Report::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->with('reportable', 'reportable.user')
        ->get();
}
```

This resulted in no error, which is good, but it also ***did not*** include the user in the results.

See data: http://pastebin.com/DDfM3Ncj

**Attempt 2**. Added code to the polymorphic ***Report Model*** (can be seen at bottom):

```
protected $appends = array('target');

public function getTargetAttribute() {
    return $this->reportable->user;
}
```

This corrrectly resulted in a 'target' being added to my results holding the user of the reportable object. However this ***ALSO Mysteriously*** added the user to my reportable object, which was what I wanted at first, but now a problem since we have the user under target.

See data: http://pastebin.com/4DD8imbN

---

### Question

How do I get the user of a polymorphic relation without suddenly ending up with two.

***NOTE:*** (Below code is ***possibly*** not required for answering)

---

### Controller

```
public function getReports(t) {
    return Report::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->with('reportable')
        ->get();
}
```

---

### Models

Polymorphic Model

```
class Report extends Model {
    public function reportable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function User() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Recipe Model

```
class Recipe extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function reports() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Report', 'reportable');
    }
}
```

Comment Model

```
class RecipeComment extends Model {   
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function reports() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Report', 'reportable');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ended up with a very simple solution of always returning a user with the desired models using:

```
protected $with = array('user');
```

This obviously has a downside that there is now always a user eagerly loaded when querying for any of the mentioned models. But we feel this came as an acceptable loss, given we only have one query where the user is not required.

The downside is made even less insignificant by our use of cache, so much that we significantly prefer this solution to just ignoring the "bug" of getting two users returned.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this myself.  Im surprised this isn't more of an issue